# How to send an array with grpc request in browser?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I created a little grpc server on my machine and Im wondering how to debug array message in browser.
Example: for one field message in gRPC with handler "/greeting" and "name" field I can request

```
localhost:7000/greeting?name=Slowpoke
```

In this way I can debug and see what really happens on my server.

How to do same moves with protobuf scheme like:

```
message NamesQuery {
    repated string name = 1;
}
```

How does request in browser should look like?

Comment: You need js framework to handle request and send it to grpc, or you can handle `GET` data with your `http handler` and send this request with your app.

Comment: is there any way to do that like with "onefield" message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By trial and error, I found the following solution for next scheme with INT fields for GET request.

```
message SomeNumbers {
    repeated int list = 1;
}
```

This request:

```
localhost:7000/some-request?list=2&&list=12&&list=22
```

and I've got next message:

```
{"list":[2,12,22]}
```